# Asp.net Core MVC - Unit testing Razor Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to write UI unit tests for my MVC core project and my problem is I am not able to find a MVC view generator or  renderer that I can use in my unit test project.

I did implement a ViewRenderService for a specific requirement in another project but I cannot use it because of the dependencies cannot be injected into the unit test project.

What is a better way to approach this for dotnet core mvc? Any guidance will help.

Comment: We usually do unit test and UI test separately, can you clarify more about the scenario that requires "write UI unit tests for my MVC core project"?

Comment: I am currently writing unit tests for MVC controller where in I am able to check action methods but not anything related to HTML. How razor logic works. This is the reason why I am wondering if I can do unit test on razor views.